# Using PM2 to deploy a React app in production environment

Tags: reactjs, web-deployment, pm2

I am trying to deploy my React app on a server via PM2. My React app currently has 2 environments: prod and dev. So, in my app folder, I have an environments folder with 2 files: **.dev.env** and **.prod.env**. First one is used for calling local APIs, and the second one is for production API URLs. prod.env is shown below:
[image]

When I want to start the app, I use the command **npm run start:dev** or **npm run start:prod**, depending on which environment I want my app on.

The question here is, when I try to deploy my app via PM2, what command or modification should I do so that I am certain that my app is deployed in production/prod mode?

My current PM2 config file looks like this:

```
{
  apps : [
    {
      name      : "random_app", //name of my app
      script    : "npm",
      interpreter: "none",
      args: "run start:dev"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For a production environment you should be serving the built version of the React app (run `npm run build` and it will output a production-ready version of your app to the build folder).

In order to separate the environment variables, you should use .env.development and .env.production files (the built version will automatically use the .env.production file) - see [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used) for more information.

Then to serve it, you would use pm2 and serve (make sure serve is installed as well `npm install -g serve`) with a command like `pm2 serve <path/to/build/folder> <port> --spa` - more info can be found [here](https://www.loginradius.com/blog/engineering/react-app-deployment/).