# MERN application running in 'development' through PM2

Tags: reactjs, nginx, build, pm2, production

I have this line in the `App.js` of my React app:

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

When running the app in development I see 'development' in the console as expected.

When I run `npm run build` then serve my app with `serve -s build` I then see 'production' in the console, which is great.

But when I run `npm run build` using nginx and try to launch my app with `pm2 start npm -- start` I still see 'development' in the console.

I have tried using `serve` in production which seems to work as a temporary fix but my session soon times out and the entire application gets disconnected.

I have also tried creating a new PM2 configuration file like this:

```
//ecosystem.config.js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'my-react-app',
      script: 'serve',
      args: ['-s', 'build'],
      instances: 1,
      autorestart: true,
      watch: false,
      max_memory_restart: '1G',
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production',
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

and starting my app with the command `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`

But I still see 'development' in the console.

I have also tried adding the `--env production` flag to the `pm2 start` command like this `pm2 start --env production npm start` but still the same result.

Any help or ideas would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74126120/13146212

Key was to use `serve` with `pm2`

Hope this helps someone else out someday